# Pandas Multiindex selecting row skipping one level

Tags: pandas

It seems to simple but my solution ends up being quite complicated.

I have df with 3 level multiindex and I want to pick row based on levels 0 and 2 while ignoring values at level 1 (but not deleting this level).

`df
L0 L1 L2  colA colB
A1 B1 C1  1    2
      C2  3    4
   B2 C1  5    6
      C2  7    8
A2 B3 C1  9   10
      C2 11   12 
   B4 C1 13   14
      C2 15   16`

Here I'd like to extract rows based on A and C leaving B untouched.

df.loc[[A,:,C],colB] doesn't work.

I have work around by manipulating multiindex levels but it is pretty complicated (for me) and there should be simpler solution.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [slicers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df1 = df.loc[idx['A1',:,'C1'],'colB']
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.loc[('A1',slice(None),'C1'),'colB']

print (df1)
L0  L1  L2
A1  B1  C1    2
    B2  C1    6
Name: colB, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to uses `loc` with `(axis=0)`, per [pandas documenation on using slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
df.loc(axis=0)['A1',:,'C1']
```

Output:

```
          colA  colB
L0 L1 L2            
A1 B1 C1     1     2
   B2 C1     5     6
```

Answer (score 3):

New in [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#multiindex-query-syntax) 0.22

```
df.query('ilevel_0=="A1" & ilevel_2=="C1"')
```

In your case it should be

```
df.query('L0=="A1" & L2=="C1"')   
Out[187]: 
          colA  colB
L0 L1 L2            
A1 B1 C1     1     2
   B2 C1     5     6
```

Answer (score 2):

`xs` will also accomplish this nicely:

```
df
          colA  colB
L0 L1 L2            
A1 B1 C1     1     2
      C2     3     4
   B2 C1     5     6
      C2     7     8
A2 B3 C1     9    10
      C2    11    12
   B4 C1    13    14
      C2    15    16

df.xs(['A1', 'C1'], level=[0,2], drop_level=False)
          colA  colB
L0 L1 L2            
A1 B1 C1     1     2
   B2 C1     5     6
```

Comment: Thanks everybody. Great help. All I have to do now is speed tests :)

Comment: Rough results: 
idx - 6.35 ms ± 216 µs // 
'loc /slice(None - 5.47 ms ± 65.5 µs // 
loc(axis=0) - 4.87 ms ± 70.1 µs //
query - 30.5 ms ± 597 µs //
xs 3.02 ms ± 63.5 µs but it was measured little different as I asked here for data from only one column while in other tests from two. I think I'll try to use xs inside .loc.

Again, thanks a lot for help.